# How to make the div center of it's parent when it has the float style

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div style="float:left"></div>
</div>
```

When the child `div` has a `float` style, how can I make it centered in its parent?

sorry , my English is so poor that I can't describe my question exactly.

I use the following pictures to describe hope you can understand

[image: each of the child div has the float style, How to make them horizontally centered in the parent div？]

Comment: And where do you want the child div to be when it does **not** float?

Comment: The simple answer is don't float and use `margin: 0 auto`, but I guess that is not an option for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table/table-cell` which will work if the element is, or isn't `floated`.

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}

.parent{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.parent>div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: calc(100% /5);
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/o5k4L0rv/3/)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,yesterday I did not clearly describe my problem, now I add that the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `position: absolute` and `transform: translateX`:

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="child" style="float: left"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="child" style="float: right"></div>
</div>
```

This works whether the child has a `float` style or not.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/difiha/3/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Your suggestion is very good, but yesterday I did not clearly describe my problem, now I add that the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
.parent {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: /*same like float div*/;
}
```